# PayPal Express Checkout won't redirect to Paypal.com

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

This is my website: http://boostingfactory.com/heroes-of-the-storm/rank-boost/

Test a random checkout and you'll see it just won't redirect to Paypal.com

I actually talked to their Technical support they told me that the module successfully requests a token but just doesn't redirect to the payment on paypal.com for some reason.

This is the module: http://pastebin.com/wbgTs35b

What do you think could be causing this?

This line particularly:

```
function RedirectToPayPal ( $token ) { 
  global $PAYPAL_URL;
  $payPalURL = $PAYPAL_URL . $token; 
  header("Location: ".$payPalURL); 
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to read through to find what could by a number of things. Do you have any more info? Any errors being returned by PHP, or do you get any response data from the Paypal API? Have you tried testing your code at the point after it successfully requests a token? Such as echoing out what happens next? That would be your starting point, as that is (so far) where your failure is.

Comment: Thank you for your response James.

I provided the link of my website feel free to try to checkout and see what happens :)

The technical support guy said the token is successfully requested because he tested my module in some different environment, the guy who coded the module for me tested in sandbox and it worked too but now when it's live on my website it doesn't redirect to the paypal.com to actually pay for it.

So basically we've isolated the problem there, it just doesn't redirect and the code looks right so I'm confused.

Comment: Going to your website will only confirm what you have already said - I won't be redirected. What does happen instead of redirect? Do you have redirect code on your site?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't clarify that I have very basic coding skills, I thought the module itself redirects to Paypal's payment page?

This line particularly:

'  function RedirectToPayPal ( $token )
        {
                global $PAYPAL_URL;
              
                // Redirect to paypal.com here
                $payPalURL = $PAYPAL_URL . $token;
                header("Location: ".$payPalURL);
        } 


Sorry for the bad formatting, can I present the code better? These backticks don't seem to be working.

Comment: All relevant info should be in the question (you can edit) unless just comment discussions of course. Ok so what happens if you do this: In front of the `header()` add `//` and underneath on a new line add `echo $payPalURL; exit();` show us the output.

Comment: PayPal responds to your setexpresscheckout with a token, if you call it correctly. Then it's your scripts job to redirect. If it doesn't, see if you have got a valid token, and if so, check the redirecting code. Maybe before header is called, the page header is already set so it doesn't redirect.

Comment: Thank you both, I got this link written on my site now after following James's code:

https://www.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-1DX37323U3293122R

Seems to be a valid link for the payment but I need it redirected automatically.

Comment: What does your error log say? It might be that headers are already sent.

Comment: Not an error, it's a link with checkout to paypal that works :)

Just need it redirected automatically now somehow, what should I add to the code?

Comment: James would you mind helping me in this last step?

Comment: I'm not a Php dev - One thing I see is that there is no `Location` header, nor status (`3.x`) returned to the client as one would expect from the snippet you provided/pointed out - this is only _part_ of the _"why"_ though..

Comment: Thing is I just tested it, the payment link works but I need it to be automatically redirected to it and not written in my webpage so the client manually has to copy paste it in browser tab, this sounds fairly simple to do?